# How to calculate median for each row from file in bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to calculate the median for each row from a file in my bash shell script. I believe there is a way to achieve this by using a pipelined command of cut, sort, head, and tail but I cannot figure out how to integrate this process into the code that I have existing. I want to calculate the median at the same point where I am calculating the mean. What is the best way to do this?

```
while read i
do
    sum=0
    count=0
    mean=0
    median=0
    for num in $i
    do
        sum=$(($sum + $num))
        count=`expr $count + 1`
        mean=`expr $sum / $count`
        #Need to calculate the median
    done
    echo "Sum: $sum Mean: $mean"
done < $2
```

Comment: "What is the best way to do this?"  - Probably not in a shell script :-)

Comment: try searching here for `[awk] average `. I see 600+ Q/As. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the rows are of variable length:

1. Using `bash` and [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

   ```
   while read x
   do    tr -s '\t' '\n' <<< "$x" | \
         datamash  median 1
   done < file
   ```
2. Using [`numaverage`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

   ```
   while read x
   do    tr -s '\t' '\n' <<< "$x" | \
         numaverage -M
   done < file
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '{sum=0; 
      n=split($0,a); 
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) sum+=a[i]; 
      asort(a); 
      median=n%2?a[n/2+1]:(a[n/2]+a[n/2+1])/2; 
      print sum, sum/n, median}' file
```

`bash` is not the right tool for this task.

Comment: Note: asort in awk is only available in the gnu version of awk.